# FFMPEG: extract a fram from a live stream once every 5 seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm tryin gto extract a single frame from a live stream, every 5 seconds without using the -vf option. I'm using a Raspberry Pi so CPU is all important.

Basically, I'm streaming a UDP stream from a live source, which uses very little CPU but I want to take a snapshot every 5 seconds.

This works, but only produces a single image.

```
-c copy -f mpegts udp://239.0.0.1:1234 -vcodec copy -vframes 1 out.png
```

This works, but uses all the CPU and more.

```
-c copy -f mpegts udp://239.0.0.1:1234 -vcodec copy -vf fps=1 out%d.png
```

Anyone know if I can do this without using a filter? My other solution is to run a second ffmpeg and connect to the UDP stream, which is really cumbersome.

Comment: What's the video codec of the feed? If it's not an intraframe codec, then many frames will have to decoded. What's your full command and console output?

Comment: It's H.264, so yes, Intraframe, but I have I frames every 1s. Also, I'm quite happy to take the image in a raw (yuv) format if that's any help. I can turn it into a JPG on te client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your keyframes are one per second, and you want one frame every 5 seconds, some filtering is needed, unless you are okay with deleting 4 out of every 5 images created.

Here's the template that creates one frame for every 5 seconds, assuming that keyframe interval is 1/s.

```
ffmpeg -i ... -c copy -map 0 -f tee "[f=mpegts]udp://239.0.0.1:1234|[f=mpegts]pipe:" | ffmpeg -f mpegts -skip_frame nokey -i pipe: -vf select='not(mod(n,5))' -vsync 0 out%d.png
```

and here's for dumping each keyframe as an image and then removing unneeded ones:

```
ffmpeg -i ... -c copy -map 0 -f tee "[f=mpegts]udp://239.0.0.1:1234|[f=mpegts]pipe:" | ffmpeg -f mpegts -skip_frame nokey -i pipe: -vsync 0 out%d.png
```

The piping syntax `pipe:` works here on Windows. Believe it should work on linux as well.