# Extract frames from live youtube stream

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming, youtube-dl

I want to extract frames from a youtube live event, say one frame every 5 minutes, ideally without saving the stream to my local machine. Is there a simple way to do this, possibly a combination between `youtube-dl` and `ffmpeg` that I am not figuring out? I found a similar question for UDP streams but don't know how to include the youtube stream: [FFMPEG: extract a fram from a live stream once every 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612315/ffmpeg-extract-a-fram-from-a-live-stream-once-every-5-seconds)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out based on [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230481/how-to-download-portion-of-video-with-youtube-dl-command) and the [ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video).

You need to convert your **youtube URL** as follows:

```
youtube-dl -g "youtube URL"
```

Copy the **output URL** into the following command to extract a frame every 5 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i "output URL" -vf fps=1/5 out%d.png
```

This will extract one frame every 5 seconds.